# Convert a json date column in google bigdata sql query

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get a column in a table and the value of the column is a json string containing a date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  contact_date, 
  JSON_value(contact_date, '$.value') as date1
FROM arcus.encounter
```

The code produces this error

> error: No matching signature for function JSON_VALUE for argument types: DATETIME, STRING. Supported signature: JSON_VALUE(STRING, [STRING]) at [3:3]

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  contact_date, 
FROM arcus.encounter    
LIMIT 5
```

```
{
  "value": "2014-11-05T00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: According to the error message, the column is already a date.

Comment: What is the schema of the table you're working on ? (more precisely the arcus.encounter contact_date). The JSON_VALUE function operates on STRING representation of JSON and it seems your column doesn't match that requirement.

Comment: @Cylldby the `contact_date` column contains a JSON string instead of a character string.  The question is how to get  the value in that JSON string into a date format.  Saying that what was tried doesn't work, misses the point that if it did work, there would be no point in posting a question to SO.

Comment: @HarlanNelson Indeed my question was not very on point. My point was that we need more info on how the table is built. When I try to reproduce the issue with SELECT JSON_VALUE("{\"value\": \"2014-11-05T00:00:00\"}", '$.value') AS result ... no error on my side..

Answer (score 0):

Both the arguments of the JSON_VALUE function should be string. ie,JSON_VALUE(STRING, [STRING]).
From the error message it is clear that the type of contact_date is DATETIME. That is why the function returns an error. In order to work with JSON_VALUE the type of contact_type should be string.

For More Clarification Refer the below link,

[JSON_VALUE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value)